# Significato di "arbarella"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Nostra madre raddoppiò la sua lavorazione di formaggio fermentato, ma non ce ne lasciava toccare neanche le briciole sull’orlo della conca. E quando seppe che a Niella ne pagavano l’**arbarella** un soldo di piú che al nostro paese, andò a venderlo a Niella, e saputo poi che a Murazzano lo pagavano qualcosa meglio, si faceva due colline per andarlo a vendere lassú.

Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il termine **arbarella** o [**arbanella**](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbanella) è dialettale e viene utilizzato in Liguria e nel basso Piemonte per indicare un barattolo di vetro per alimenti.

> **Arbanella** è un termine in uso nella lingua ligure per definire un tipo
>   particolare di barattolo in vetro, utile come contenitore per alimenti
>   e conserve dolci e salate.
>
> In italiano esistono termini affini ad arbanella come albarello
>   (contenitore a uso erboristico o farmaceutico, solitamente di
>   maiolica), da cui la parola potrebbe essere derivata attraverso la
>   dissimilazione della *r* in *n* e un fenomeno di rotacismo.
>
> In alcune zone del ponente ligure è diffusa la variante dialettale
>   **erbanella**, mentre in alcune zone dello spezzino e della Lunigiana il
>   suono della *r* diventa una *l* in **albanella**.
>
> Il termine si è diffuso anche nel basso Piemonte. In particolare,
>   nella zona del monregalese, si è diffusa la variante con doppio
>   rotacismo **arbarella**. Da qui le espressioni: pesche in arbarella,
>   arbarella di marmellata, vado in cantina a prendere un'arbarella...

Come si vede il termine era diffuso nelle zone del monregalese cioè nella provincia di Cuneo, di cui fanno parte Niella Tanaro e Murazzano.

Alla voce "arbarella" del [Vocabolario piemontese-italiano e italiano-piemontese, del sacerdote Michele Ponza](http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/vocabolario-piemontese-italiano-di-michele-ponza), un vocabolario storico dell'Ottocento, si trova:

> *Arbarella, n.* alberello (*vas da spëssiari*).

Secondo Treccani il termine [alberello](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alberello1) significa:

> 3. Vaso (detto anche *albarello*), per lo più di maiolica dipinta, più raramente di vetro e in origine, forse, di legno di pioppo (da cui
>      deriverebbe il nome); di forma generalmente cilindrica, con una
>      rastrematura centrale che lo rende simile a un segmento di bambù, fu
>      usato in passato dagli speziali (e in Francia, nel sec. 18°, come
>      insegna di farmacie), ma in seguito anche come barattolo per
>      confetture, colori o altri materiali: *l’a. del sale, l’a. delle
>      acciughe; alberelli di lattovari e d’unguenti colmi* (Boccaccio);
>      *meglio al bosco un vermicciol gli aggrada Che in gabbia un a. di
>      panico* (Pascoli).

Comment: Tuttavia, in questo testo sembra riferirsi al contenuto del barattolo (formaggio fermentato).

Comment: Anche alla voce "arbarella" del [Vocabolario piemontese-italiano e italiano-piemontese, del sacerdote Michele Ponza](https://archive.org/details/vocabolariopiem05ponzgoog), un vocabolario storico dell'Ottocento, si trova: «*Arbarella, n.* alberello (*vas da spëssiari*)».

Comment: Che, secondo il vocabolario Treccani significa: «Vaso (detto anche *albarello*), per lo più di maiolica dipinta, più raramente di vetro e in origine, forse, di legno di pioppo (da cui deriverebbe il nome); di forma generalmente cilindrica, con una rastrematura centrale che lo rende simile a un segmento di bambù, fu usato in passato dagli speziali (e in Francia, nel sec. 18°, come insegna di farmacie), ma in seguito anche come barattolo per confetture, colori o altri materiali».

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alberello1

Comment: @Charo Ottima ricerca, aggiunte le informazioni alla risposta

Comment: In realtà nel testo si riferisce all'arbarella piena di formaggio fermentato.  È da intendere: E quando seppe che a Niella pagavano un soldo in piú rispetto al nostro paese per ogni arbarella (di formaggio fermentato)...